# Paragraph indentation

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I am trying to get TeX to indent every new paragraph, but have not been successful after trying many different preambles.

Currently, this is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\title{Sections and Chapters}
   %\date{ }
%\setlength{\parident}{10ex}
\linespread{1.7}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{12}\sffamily}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{12}\sffamily}
\raggedright

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{ 
  \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}% 
                 {23pt}% 
                 {23pt}% 
                 {\normalsize\sffamily}} 
\renewcommand\subsection{ 
  \@startsection {subsection}{1}{\z@}% 
                 {23pt}% 
                 {23pt}% 
                 {\normalsize\sffamily}} 
\renewcommand\subsubsection{ 
  \@startsection {subsubsection}{1}{\z@}% 
                 {23pt}% 
                 {23pt}% 
                 {\normalfont\normalsize\sffamily}} 
\makeatother
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\thesection   {\@Roman\c@section .}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection   {{\hspace{2em}}\@Alph\c@subsection .}
    \renewcommand\thesubsubsection   {{\hspace{2em}}\@arabic\c@subsubsection .}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
```

Does any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently, the `\raggedright` invocation gets rid of the default indentation.  As unxnut says in the answer, you can explicitly add in `\parindent`.  Otherwise, you can ditch the `\raggedright`.

Comment: apart from dropping `\raggedright` note that the `%` in your section definitions have no effect on the output, but you are missing a `%` in each case after the `{` which could affect the output.

Answer (score 5):

You issue `\raggedright`, which is defined as (in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\raggedright{%
  \let\\\@centercr\@rightskip\@flushglue \rightskip\@rightskip
  \leftskip\z@skip
  \parindent\z@}
```

The last line of `\raggedright` sets `\parindent` to 0pt. As such, you need to set to to suit your needs. For example, you could use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@tempdima}{\parindent}% Save \parindent
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{\@tempdima}% Restore \parindent
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `ragged2e` which enhances ragged-right typesetting by allowing hyphenation and improving line-breaking, and which also makes the paragraph indentation easily configurable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{\parindent}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: ragged right]

Answer (score 2):

The directive `\raggedright`, if inserted in the preamble, applies only to material in the main "body" of the document -- but *not* to footnotes, `minipage` environments, and `p`-type columns in `tabular` and `array` environments. I suppose you could remedy this by inserting the instruction `\raggedright` at the start of every footnote and minipage as well. However, that's tedious and error-prone, isn't it? Moreover, hyphenation is disabled by `\raggedright`, which can cause extremely ragged-looking output.

Instead of using `\raggedright`, then, I suggest you load the `ragged2e` package with the option `document`. Doing so will apply ragged-right typesetting to all parts of the documents, and it will also (re)enable hyphenation.

To set the indentation of the first lines to a nonzero value, use `\setlength\RaggedRightParindent{<some length value>}`.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\setlength\RaggedRightParindent{0.75cm} % indentation of first line of a paragraph
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\setlength\textheight{11.5cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

\bigskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
\lipsum*[4]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

If you comment out (or delete) the instructions `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` and `\setlength\RaggedRightParindent{0.75cm}` and insert `\raggedright` instead, you'll notice that the minipage and footnote materials are both typeset fully-justified -- probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `\parindent` directive?  You could add

```
\setlength\parindent{0.2in}
```

to indent by .2 inches.  You could use the units of your choice (cm, pt).

Comment: The standard indentation of LaTeX is `\parindent=20.0pt`.